# How to hide a private key in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, private-key, mercadopagosdk

I am making an application in flutter and I am using a payment gateway, specifically the [MercadoPago SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/mercadopago_sdk). This SDK needs a series of keys for its correct operation but i use them in the following class saved in Strings to use them in the application:

This is my globals.dart

```
    library my_prj.globals;

    String mpTESTPublicKey = "TEST-ABCDEFG";
    String mpTESTAccessToken = "TEST-HIJKLM";
    
    String mpPublicKey = "APP_USR-123456";
    String mpAccessToken = "APP_USR-78910";
    
    String mpClientID = "1234566789";
    String mpClientSecret = "A1B2C3D4E5";
```

I find myself using these keys as follows in the application:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> buildPreference() async {
    var email = common.email;
    var name = common.displayName;

    var mp = MP(globals.mpClientID, globals.mpClientSecret); //Client secret ID
    var preference = {
      "items": [
        {
          'title': common.title,
          'quantity': 1,
          'currency_id': 'COP',
          'unit_price': common.price
        }
      ],
      'payer': {'name': name, 'email': email},
    };

    var result = await mp.createPreference(preference);
    return result;
  }

Future<void> executeMercadoPago() async {
    buildPreference().then((result) {
      if (result != null) {
        var preferenceId = result['response']['id'];
        try {
          const channelMercadoPago =
              const MethodChannel("example.com/mercadoPago");
          final response = channelMercadoPago.invokeMethod(
              'mercadoPago', <String, dynamic>{
            "publicKey": globals.mpTESTPublicKey, //Public test  key
            "preferenceId": preferenceId
          });
          print(response);
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print(e.message);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

However, researching I found that when releasing the application, it is possible for people to have access to the code and information of these keys, for this I would like to know if there is any way to use this information within the application with full security.

I have thought of encrypting these Strings, however, I do not know if this encryption can be accessed and then they can easily decrypt it.